# Making a mold to impart a surface texture to wet concrete

Tags: concrete, texture

I want to simulate a rock-face effect (see photo) on the edge of a concrete slab that will be 12x48 inches and 2 inches thick.  I have a stone stair tread with the desired edge surface texture to use as the template.

I was going to build a wooden frame around the stone stair tread, leaving a gap of about an inch along the length of one side, into which a liquid would be poured and allowed to set. I'll put some kind of base underneath and seal it to prevent leakage.

The mold must peel away from the stone easily after it cures and it must peel off the cured concrete slab without tearing. It must be durable enough to be reused multiple times; I need to make about a dozen of these slabs.

I need about ~96 cubic inches for the mold.

Is silicon a good choice given those requirements?

[image: rock-face stair tread]

Comment: Silicone might work, but I think it would be too soft/rubbery as a stamp for cement.  Something like an epoxy or maybe clay, should work better as a stamp.  Think you can use an oil or plastic wrap for peeling/protection of the step.

Comment: As a _mold_ for pouring concrete into, I'd think silicone would be nearly ideal. However, I'd suggest doing some research - a quick search for "how to make diy concrete molds and forms" seems to have turned up dozens of pages. Many of them are, I'm sure, for traditional square forms, but there were a number that referenced silicone molds and others that indicated non-square/straight shapes, so I'm certain you'll find good answers.

Comment: @FreeMan:   There are, as you say, plenty of "how to" pages out there, and I am indeed researching, but I came here hoping to find some *advice* from someone who might have already tried to do it.